# I need an auto hide function to use on a website (Java Script)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to coding, but looking at doing a bootcamp to help me learn some more, however, at the moment I am having some trouble getting some code to do what I need it to.

The following code is what I use on the website I'm working on:

```
<button class="zerobut" onclick="myFunction5()">Open</button>

<script>
function myFunction5() {
  var x = document.getElementById("product5");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>
```

What I need is an automatic hide once a different button is clicked. There are 5 different categories from which a customer must choose before the options are displayed, but at the moment it doesn't close the previous option unless you click on the button again.

Is anyone able to help me understand what I need to change to make this happen? (sorry if I'm explaining this poorly.)

Here's another section's code. So when this one opens, the first one should close automatically if possible.
`

```
<button class="healthbut" onclick="myFunction3()">Open2</button>

<script>
    function myFunction3() {
      var x = document.getElementById("product3");
      if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
</script>
```

`

Comment: Please post the full code with the other five elements so its easier to understand.

Comment: I added another section to the thread. Thank you.

It's all the same code, but in 5 different code boxes with different names. I hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work the first time because the style.display attribute is initially set to the empty string. If you add the style attribute it works.

```js
function myFunction5() {
  var x = document.getElementById("product5");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.products {
background-color:yellow;
border: 1px solid black;
padding:1rem;
}
```

```html
<button class="zerobut" onclick="myFunction5()">Open/Close</button>

<div class = 'products' style='display:block' id='product5'>Product 5 panel</div>
```

A better option is to just check to see if your style.display attribute is not 'none' and change it otherwise as below

```js
function myFunction5() {
  var x = document.getElementById("product5");
  if (x.style.display !== "none") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.products {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<button class="zerobut" onclick="myFunction5()">Open/Close</button>

<div class='products' id='product5'>Product 5 panel</div>
```

Finally, an even better way to do it is to create a 'hide' class and toggle the class element

```js
function myFunction5() {
  var x = document.getElementById("product5");
  x.classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

```css
.products {
background-color:yellow;
border: 1px solid black;
padding:1rem;
}

.products.hide {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="zerobut" onclick="myFunction5()">Open/Close</button>

<div class = 'products' id='product5'>Product 5 panel</div>
```

Finally, if you've got some panels you need to hide when you're displaying others, then this can be done as follows:

```js
productNumber = 1;
totalNumberOfProducts = 5;

function myFunction5() {
  //Select all elements with the class 'products'.
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".products");
  
  //choose the next element to display
  productNumber++;
  
  //If we get past the last element then go back to the one with id 'product1'
  if (productNumber > totalNumberOfProducts) {
    productNumber = 1;
  }
  
  //Loop through each element and hide all elements except the one that's got the id of
  //"product"+productNumber;
  elements.forEach((element) => {
      const elementId = element.getAttribute('id');
      if (elementId == 'product' + productNumber) {
        element.classList.remove('hide');
      } else {
        element.classList.add('hide');
      }
    });
  }
```

```css
.products {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#product1 {
  background-color: brown;
}

#product2 {
  background-color: salmon;
}

#product3 {
  background-color: pink;
}

#product4 {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

#product5 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.products.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <button class="zerobut" onclick="myFunction5()">Go to next panel</button>

<div class='products' id='product1'>Product 1 panel</div>
<div class='products hide' id='product2'>Product 2 panel</div>
<div class='products hide' id='product3'>Product 3 panel</div>
<div class='products hide' id='product4'>Product 4 panel</div>
<div class='products hide' id='product5'>Product 5 panel</div>
```

Comment: Do you know of a way that I can make the first section close when I click on the next one? Instead of having to click the button again?

Comment: I'll add an example to the answer